# Unit Testing HttpContext overwrites behavior of ISitecorecontext

Tags: sitecore, nunit

In my test class i mocked the sitecore context like below to get items from my fake database:

`ISitecoreContext _sitecoreContext = new SitecoreContext();`

After this I tried to switch the logged in user as below :

`using (new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(@"extranet\John", true))
  {
    // Do something
  }`

Eveything is working fine until I needed to set the value of `HttpContext.Current` which I added before the instantiation of sitecore context object

`HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
    new HttpRequest("", "http://tempuri.org", ""),
    new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())
    );`

Now when I tried to debug my code, the line that switched another user is throwing an error

`Value cannot be null, parameter name : folder`

Why is it happening? Does the `httpcontext` overwrites the context of `isitecorecontext`?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. There is not enough details in the question in its current state.

Comment: @Nkosi those are all the details I can provide.

Comment: @Sherlock at minimum you should include full stack trace. From the look of it seems sitecore is expecting some kind of info your mocked context is not providing.